# oracle rollback changes through several transactions

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible to track changes made in session transactions? I need somehow to track all changes that are made in the my session. That is necessary for testing purpose - after test is finished I need to remove all changes made during this test, so I will be able to run this test again without changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several options to deal with this situation - since you don't provide much detail I can only can give some general pointers:

- temporary tables (session-specific vsersus global, you can decide to preserve or automatically throw away) see  http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm
- Flashback area - this one can rollback the whole DB to a specific point in time and thus reverse all change across several transactions see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/availability/flashback-overview-082751.html
- create "prepare" scripts for your test scenarios which reset the DB to a known state before every test

Answer (score 0):

There are many things you can do with oracle as an administrator, especially if your test database is on a filesystem that supports snapshots.

However, if you're looking at this from a unit test perspective purely as a developer,  the safest/cleanest way to handle something like this is to:

- truncate the tables involved in the test
- load the fixture/test/known state data
- run your tests